# Why won't setState render? Says cannot render property value of undefined

Tags: reactjs

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    //import NameInput from './NameInput';

    class NameInput extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        }
        handleChange(event) {
            this.props.onNameChange(event.target.value);
        }

        render() {
            const name = this.props.name;
            return(
                <input type="text" value={name} onChange={this.handleChange} />
            );
        }

    }







    class NameForm extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {name: ''};
```

Start of broken code.  This code will not work for some reason.  It is supposed to lift up the state of the input from the child component NameInput to the parent component NameForm.  So whatever value the user enters into the input box once they press submit the name should appear in a written message.

```
        this.nameChange = this.nameChange.bind(this);
```

End of first part of broken code.  nameChange is connected to a function in the NameInput component.  For some reason it comes up as undefined and the setState change event doesn't take place.

```
            this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        }
```

Start of broken code.  Why won't this part work work?  Why does this come up as undefined?  This is the exact location where the error occurs.  nameChange won't work correctly and the name property won't evaluate or the state won't update for some reason.

```
            nameChange(event) {
                        this.setState({name: event.target.value});
                        }
```

End of broken code.  This is the end of the broken code.  This is the area where the code will not function correctly.  I can't figure out why it isn't working and why the setState in this change handler won't work.  Can you please help my to figure it out and fix the problem?

```
handleSubmit(event) {
        alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.name);
        event.preventDefault();
        }

        render() {
            const name = this.state.name;
            return (
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <label>
                    Name:
                    <NameInput  name={name} onNameChange={this.nameChange}/>
                </label>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                </form>
            );
        }
    }
    export default NameForm;
```

Comment: please create a sandbox or try to provide the full code in one go, so that we can understand your problem, it is really hard to understand with the separate pieces of code.

Comment: Looks like you are not passing an event to your change handler in form, like you expected to.... take a look at how the input change handler is calling the form change handler, and make sure it is passing the correct object...

Answer (score 0):

If you still have not resolved it, based on Garrett's comment, here's a visual representation that may help.

> nameChange(**event**) {   this.setState({name: event.target.value}); }
>
> handleChange(event) {    this.props.onNameChange(**event.target.value**); 
>   }

As he states, your nameChange method is expecting to receive an event object. However, you're not passing it an event object; instead, you've passed it the value.